# Access nested XML data in parent node using R dataframe

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

Screenshot of XML file

[image]

When I try to convert the document to a dataframe I got the entire node on each column because the nodes are nested into a parent one

[image: results on R studio]

My code

```
require(XML)
data <- xmlInternalTreeParse("test2.xml")
df <- xmlToDataFrame(data)
```

How do I specify the parent node `row` in the last line of code?

I tried

```
df <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(data, "//row"))
```

It gives me error

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, names(nodes[[i]]), value = c(row
> = "41021206Frankford2NORTHEASTERN",  :    duplicate subscripts for columns

Comment: Have you tried something like `xml2::xml_find_first("\\response\\row")`?

Comment: no applicable method for 'xml_find_first' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: And the parent node is not response is row

Comment: Well you have to specify the xml object, with `xml2::read_xml(file)`. It would find row that has response as an ancestor.

Comment: It seems to be returning the correct row like  [1] <row>\n  <row _id="1" _uuid="93CACF6F-C8C2-4B87-95A8-8177806D5A6F"

Comment: I don't understand your answer, the data I'm looking for is still nested inside parent

Answer (score 0):

To access childrens nodes you have to specify name of parent like so

```
df <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(data, "//row//row"))
```